# Using effect of Traversable [] and Applicative Maybe in lens library

Tags: haskell, data-manipulation, haskell-lens

I have the following structure:

```hs
y = [
  fromList([("c", 1 ::Int)]),
  fromList([("c", 5)]),
  fromList([("d", 20)])
  ]
```

I can use this to update every "c":

```hs
y & mapped . at "c" . mapped  %~ (+ 1)
-- [fromList [("c",2)], fromList [("c",6)], fromList [("d",20)]]
```

So the third entry is basically just ignored. But I want is for the operation to fail.

> Only update, iff all the maps contain the key "c".

So I want:

```hs
y & mysteryOp
-- [fromList [("c",1)], fromList [("c",5)], fromList [("d",20)]]
-- fail because third entry does not contain "c" as key
```

I think I know which functions to use here:

```hs
over
-- I want to map the content of the list

mapped
-- map over the structure and transform to [(Maybe Int)]

traverse
-- I need to apply the operation, which will avoid 

at "c"
-- I need to index into the key "c"
```

I just don't know how to combine them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of alternative approaches seeing as you like lenses;

Using laziness to delay deciding whether or not to make the changes,

```
f y = res
  where (All c, res) = y 
                     & each %%~ (at "c" %%~ (Wrapped . is _Just &&& fmap (applyWhen c succ)))
```

Or deciding upfront whether to make the changes,

```
f' y = under (anon y $ anyOf each (nullOf $ ix "c")) (mapped . mapped . ix "c" +~ 1) y
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to write it as a simple composition of lens combinators, but this is a traversal that you can write from scratch.  It should either traverse all values of `"c"` keys if every map contains such a key or else traverse no values.

We can start with a helper function to "maybe" update a map with a new key value, failing in the `Maybe` monad if the key doesn't exist.  For reasons that will become apparent, we want to allow the update to occur in an arbitrary functor.  That is, we want a function:

```
maybeUpdate :: (Functor f, Ord k) => k -> (v -> f v) -> Map k v -> Maybe (f (Map k v))
```

Is that signature clear?  We check for the key `k`.  *If* the key is found, we'll return `Just` an updated map with the key's corresponding value `v` updated in the `f` functor.  *Otherwise*, if the key is not found, we return `Nothing`.  We can write this pretty clearly in monad notation, though we need the `ApplicativeDo` extension if we only want to use `Functor f` constraint:

```
maybeUpdate :: (Functor f, Ord k) => k -> (v -> f v) -> Map k v -> Maybe (f (Map k v))
maybeUpdate k f m = do            -- in Maybe monad
  v <- m ^. at k
  return $ do                     -- in "f" functor
    a <- f v
    return $ m & at k .~ Just a
```

Alternatively, these "monadic actions" are really just functor actions, so this definition can be used:

```
maybeUpdate' k f m =
  m ^. at k <&> \v -> f v <&> \a -> m & at k .~ Just a
```

That's the hard part.  Now, the traversal is pretty straightforward.  We start with the signature:

```
traverseAll :: (Ord k) => k -> Traversal' [Map k v] v
traverseAll k f maps =
```

The idea is that this traversal starts by traversing the list of maps over the `Maybe` applicative using the `maybeUpdate` helper:

```
traverse (maybeUpdate k f) maps :: Maybe [f (Map k v)]
```

If this traversal succeeds (returns `Just` a list), then all keys were found, and we can sequence the `f` applicative actions:

```
sequenceA <$> traverse (maybeUpdate k f) maps :: Maybe (f [Map k v])
```

Now, we just use `maybe` to return the original list if the traversal fails:

```
traverseAll k f maps = maybe (pure maps) id (sequenceA <$> traverse (maybeUpdate k f) maps)
```

Now, with:

```
y :: [Map String Int]
y = [
  fromList([("c", 1 ::Int)]),
  fromList([("c", 5)]),
  fromList([("d", 20)])
  ]
y2 :: [Map String Int]
y2 = [
  fromList([("c", 1 ::Int)]),
  fromList([("c", 5)]),
  fromList([("d", 20),("c",6)])
  ]
```

we have:

```
> y & traverseAll "c" %~ (1000*)
[fromList [("c",1)],fromList [("c",5)],fromList [("d",20)]]
> y2 & traverseAll "c" %~ (1000*)
[fromList [("c",1000)],fromList [("c",5000)],fromList [("c",6000),("d",20)]]
```

Full disclosure:  I was not able to construct `traverseAll` like that from scratch.  I started with the much stupider "traversal" in the implicit identity applicative:

```
traverseAllC' :: (Int -> Int) -> [Map String Int] -> [Map String Int]
traverseAllC' f xall = maybe xall id (go xall)
  where go :: [Map String Int] -> Maybe [Map String Int]
        go (x:xs) = case x !? "c" of
          Just a -> (Map.insert "c" (f a) x:) <$> go xs
          Nothing -> Nothing
        go [] = Just []
```

and once I got that up and running, I simplified it, made the `Identity` explicit:

```
traverseAllC_ :: (Int -> Identity Int) -> [Map String Int] -> Identity [Map String Int]
```

and converted it to a general applicative.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Map (Map, fromList)
import Control.Lens

y :: [Map [Char] Int]
y = [
  fromList([("c", 1 ::Int)]),
  fromList([("c", 5)]),
  fromList([("d", 20)])
  ]
y2 :: [Map [Char] Int]
y2 = [
  fromList([("c", 1 ::Int)]),
  fromList([("c", 5)]),
  fromList([("d", 20),("c",6)])
  ]

traverseAll :: (Ord k) => k -> Traversal' [Map k v] v
traverseAll k f maps = maybe (pure maps) id (sequenceA <$> traverse (maybeUpdate k f) maps)

maybeUpdate :: (Functor f, Ord k) => k -> (v -> f v) -> Map k v -> Maybe (f (Map k v))
maybeUpdate k f m = do
  v <- m ^. at k
  return $ do
    a <- f v
    return $ m & at k .~ Just a

maybeUpdate' :: (Functor f, Ord k) => k -> (v -> f v) -> Map k v -> Maybe (f (Map k v))
maybeUpdate' k f m =
  m ^. at k <&> \v -> f v <&> \a -> m & at k .~ Just a

main = do
  print $ y & traverseAll "c" %~ (1000*)
  print $ y2 & traverseAll "c" %~ (1000*)
```

Comment: `pure` for `return` and `fromMaybe e` for `maybe e id`